# Script to automate MySQLConverterTool's cli.php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using MySQLConverterTool's cli.php to convert ext/mysql functions to ext/mysqli. It works OK on the command line if I convert one file at a time, but I want to automate the process to convert an array of files.

I get the php files with: 
    find /path/to/target/directory *.php > php_files.txt

Here is my process_cli.php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $files = file('/path/to/php_files.txt');

    foreach ($files as &$file)
    {
        // cli.php -f $file -u; // returns "unexpected '$file' (T_VARIABLE)"

        // echo $file; // works

        shell_exec("php cli.php -f $file -u"); // returns "sh: 2: -u: not found" with no files converted
}
?>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working properly?

---

Results from `var_dump($file)` in the loop:

```
string(35) "/home/bill/orderstatus/sync_db.php " ... string(48) "/home/bill/orderstatus/templates/searchForm.php " string(59) "/home/bill/orderstatus/templates/orderDetailRegistered.php " string(36) "/home/bill/orderstatus/database.php " string(33) "/home/bill/orderstatus/index.php "
```

Comment: Is your `foreach` not working? You have to have the full path to each `$file` to act on it.

Comment: Yes, the foreach is working; note the echo $file; works and the $files array contains the full path to each file.

Comment: Have you tried without passing the file by reference?

Comment: Just tried that with the same results.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($file)` on each iteration and post thos results here?

Comment: string(35) "/home/bill/orderstatus/sync_db.php
"
...

string(48) "/home/bill/orderstatus/templates/searchForm.php
"
string(59) "/home/bill/orderstatus/templates/orderDetailRegistered.php
"
string(36) "/home/bill/orderstatus/database.php
"
string(33) "/home/bill/orderstatus/index.php
"

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run the process? It seems that since you're invoking PHP during the loop you'll need to place the full path there to: `shell_exec("/usr/bin/php ...`

Comment: Well, php is in my path, but I tried that anyway and got the same "sh: 2: -u: not found" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working.

I added a str_replace to get rid of the trailing space in the $files entries and simply moved the u argument before the f argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  $files = file('/path/to/php_files.txt');

  foreach ($files as $file)
  {
    $file = str_replace(' ', '', $file);
    shell_exec("/usr/bin/php cli.php -u -f $file");
  }
?>
```